# rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2)) waiting for download

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, esp-idf

I am trying to run a simple hello world sketch using Visual Studio Code for ESP32. To upload and to see the response,
I typed "idf.py flash monitor" in terminal. It uploads successfully, but after upload, the messages said:

```
ets Jun 8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))
waiting for download
```

I am using ESP32 development board. 38 pin board.
[Here, I have attached the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bODh0.png)

So far I have worked only in Arduino IDE. I am new to ESP-IDF. What is the problem here?

Comment: Could you try to manually reset the board? Just press the reset button for that. That being said, there shouldn't be any problem with `idf.py flash monitor`. The command should set the board automatically, at least as long as you use an "original" [DevKitC ESP32 board](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/devkits/esp32-devkitc).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to select exactly the chip to correctly set the boot address at https://micropython.org/download/esp32/
for example, for the ESP32 Vendor: Espressif, Features: BLE, WiFi1, is
0x1000, with the command
esptool.exe  --chip esp32 --port COM4 --baud 460800 write_flash -z 0x1000 esp32-20190125-v1.10.bin

Comment: this works. firmware location has to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

The boot rom detects the state of the gpio boot pin when it's powered up. That pin is connected to a button on development boards. If the button is pressed while powering up, software reset will go to download mode rather than booting from the flash.

So the solution is to not press the button while powering up the board. In some cases maybe the button state is incorrectly detected, so just repower the board in that case.

Answer (score 0):

press the boot button and then click reset button.
it worked out for me